# Apache RewriteRule for querystring

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite URL with querystring:

http://www.example.com/?p=121&cpage=7

to:

http://www.example.com/

What's the easiest way to do it on .htaccess?

Comment: RewriteRule ^p$ / [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
```

The {QUERY_STRING} will detect the correct query, and if the condition is met it will rewrite it to `www.example.com`.

The `?` at the end of the redirected URL is there so that the query string does not appear on the end of the URL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention I need any parameter after "p" to be ignored, basically any URL with ?p= needs to be redirected

Comment: I've updated so that anything after the parameter `p` will now be ignored (so `cpage`) and it takes any number variable related to `p`.

Comment: I was expermenting with
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p?

Comment: Having issues with this @azathoth ? I noticed you removed it as a correct answer.